# TypeError: one character string expected

Tags: python, python-2.x

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

> TypeError: one character string expected

Ругается вот на эту строку:

```
v1 = Array('c', 'name1')
```

где Array - это:

```
from multiprocessing import Array
```

За образец брал пример [отсюда](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.synchronized):

```
s = Array('c', 'hello world', lock=lock)
```

Пробовал менять 'c' на c_char (насколько я понял, 'c' - это какое-то сокращенное указание на тип ctype, хотя в сети подтверждения этому не нашел). Но ошибка все та же. Как можно ее победить?

Comment: У вас точно второй питон и ошибка точно в этой строке?

Comment: Да, точно. Номер строки указан в ошибке... В общем решил проблему, заменив 'c' на c_char_p. Но почему отказался работать пример с оф. документации так и не понял

Comment: Потому что у вас в начале файла написано `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: Да, точно. Написано)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что у вас в начале файла написано `from __future__ import unicode_literals`